# how can I display this div inline wrapping a list <ul> menu?

Tags: css, html

I have this simple css menu list  that I want to wrap in a div and put A border around it.
You can see on below link the border by default takes max width instead of wrapping around the menu list.

```
#cont
{
border: 4px solid #90bade;
display: inline;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

**[MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5je64/2/)**

I have tried to set the display mode of this div to inline and played with overflow:hidden style on div. It fixes the div border to wrap perfectly around my list But at the same time it prevents the menu drop down action.

**UPDATE #1 :**
As pointed out in Ritabrata's answer missing bit was **display:inline-block;** and there is no need for overflow: hidden;

```
#cont
{
border: 4px solid #90bade;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

couple of changes in your css ::

```
#cont
{
border: 4px solid #90bade;
overflow:hidden;
width:auto;
display:inline;
}

#nav
{
position: relative;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
display:inline-block;
}
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5je64/5/)**

**[LEARN MORE ABOUT display: HERE](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display)**

Comment: thanks seems just adding display:inline-block; would suffice here. do I need overflow:hidden ?

Comment: yes..if it was correct answer..please choose as correct or not impressed you may tell me

Comment: great , i will add a note to my post.

Comment: just updated my post. Earlier I was trying to achieve this by setting the overflow which was perhaps not the way to go in the first place. the key here as you noted in your answer is to use inline-block

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35662/discussion-between-dotnetcoder-and-ritabrata-gautam)